# What is the autocorrelation function of this energy signal?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, dsp

I would like to know how I would go about finding the autocorrelation function of this energy signal. I tried to integrate the function, but I don't know where to start.
The autocorrelation function is,
$$R(\tau)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty{ x(t)x(t-\tau)\ dt}$$
and the energy signal is defined as,
$$x(t) = e^{-3t}u(t)$$
where u(t) is a step function.
Can you please show the steps to integration?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a math question and not specifically EE related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$x(t)\$ is causal (equals zero for *t*<0). So the integration can start from *t=0*.

For \$t\ge0\$, \$x(t)=e^{-3t}\$. Substitute, factor out the constant then integrate.

Edit for completeness:

Notice that \$x(t-\tau)=0\$ for \$t<\tau\$ so the integration limits start at \$t=\tau\$

Comment: In short, remove the u(t) and only integrate from 0 to infinity, eliminating the negative range in this way.

Comment: No. u(t)=1 so it is still there for t>0. The integral for negative time is also still there, it is equal to zero. The piecewise integration from -infinity to plus infinity still works. However, the only effort required is for t>0. @CristobolPolychronopolis

Comment: Since I was integrating the multiplication of u(t)*u(t-tau), I followed @RussellH steps to integrate from 0 to infinity for when tau < 0 because u(t) will dominate. Otherwise, when tau > 0, u(t-tau) will dominate and the integration limits are from tau to infinity.  Both cases yield same result with a decaying/growth difference in the exponent to which I used the decaying term with an absolute of tau exponent.

Comment: In order to be causal, \$\tau>0\$, so the integration limits are from \$\tau\$  to \$\infty\$.